# Ionic creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

When I select an image in IOS I get the following error message in the Xcode console:

```
Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
```

I'm using Ionic 1, does anyone know how to filter this?